# Why does the direction of flow of charge depend on electric potential difference?

Tags: electrostatics

Why does electric charge flow direction depend on the potential difference and not the charge difference between two points?

Comment: A charge difference will lead to a potential difference.

Comment: Please explain what you mean.

Comment: @JonCuster There is a funny duality between the current and the voltage, most of the circuits have an equivalent circuits as well, where voltage and current are switched. For example, voltage difference leads to current, but current also leads to voltage difference.

Comment: Boulders don't roll up a hill just because there are more or less boulders at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Systems try and minimise their potential energy.
So if a charge is able to move from a position where it has a high potential energy to a position where it has a lower potential energy it will do so.

Here is an example where there is a charge difference and no flow of charges:

[image]

The metallic sphere is initially uncharged and because it is a conductor the potential of all parts of the sphere are the same.

When the negative rod is brought close to the metallic sphere electrons in the metal sphere move away from the rod and leave a surplus of positive charge close to the rod.
The electrons moved so as to reduce the potential energy of the system (rod and sphere) as compared with the potential energy the system would have had if the charges had not moved.
Note that the negative rod had tried to make the region of the sphere closest have a lower potential than that region which is furthest from the sphere.
The rod set up a potential difference across the metal sphere which become zero due to the redistribution of the electrons.

You will note that the charge distribution on the metallic sphere is asymmetric but the charges do not move because in that position the potential energy has been minimized and the potential of the metallic sphere is the same everywhere.

As the negative rod is removed there is a potential difference across the metal sphere and the electrons move to reduce the potential difference until it becomes zero.

Comment: Why is the potential energy of the system (rod and sphere) after charge separation in the sphere less as compared with the potential energy the system would have had if the charges had not moved.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "Note that the negative rod had tried to make the region of the sphere closest have a lower potential than that region which is furthest from the sphere". I think you probably meant something else.

Comment: @MrAP There is a force on the negative rod due to the induced charges. So bringing the rod closer to the sphere requires you to do negative work i.e. work is done for you.  Where does that work come from? A reduction in the potential energy of the system.

Comment: @MrAP Around the negative rod there is an electric field and hence a potential gradient. Points further from the rod are at a higher potential than points closer to the rod. The introduction of the sphere means that the final state is that where there used to be a potential gradient with the region closer to the rod more negative than the region further from the rod there is no longer a potential gradient across the sphere.  The region where the sphere is closest to the rod has gone up in potential and the region furthest from the rod gone down in potential.

Answer (score 2):

Because the potential difference is dependent on the amount of charge and hence the "charge difference" of the two points.

The  [electrostatic potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_field#Causes_and_description) $$\vec{E}(\vec{r}')=\int \rm{d} \vec{r} \rho(\vec{r}) \frac{\vec{r}-\vec{r}'}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|^3}$$ is dependent on the charge density $\rho(\vec{r}) $ which may be different along a line connecting two points A and B. The [potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential#Electrostatics) between those two points would be represented as a line integral $$V=-\int_c \vec{E} \cdot\rm {d}  \vec{l}$$ where $c$ is a path connecting the two points.

As in gravitational fields the objects in electrical fields tend to move from higher to lower potential to lower their energies.

Answer (score 2):

The electric field, ${\bf E}$ is related to the *gradient* of the potential, ${\bf E} = -\nabla  V$ and the force on a charge $q$ is ${\bf F}= q {\bf E}$. This means positive charges move in the direction of decreasing potential and negative charges move in the direction of increasing potential. The *source* of an electric field is due to charge separation of equal amounts of positive and negative charge, so in a sense, the charge $q$ will move between two places where there is a difference of charges: moving away from the charge of the same sign towards the charge of the opposite sign.

Answer (score 1):

The unit of electric potential (volt) has charge as a unit within it.

V = Joule / Coulumb

The difference in charge between two points determines how much energy you (would need to move them together) or (could get out of moving them apart). That is why we call it electric *potential*.

This also determines the direction that charge will want to move in.

Comment: But the formula represents the energy required per unit charge.

Comment: Why does the direction depend on the difference in potential energy per unit charge rather than the difference in charge?

Comment: Right. Or the energy required per difference in charge. Its all relative. I don't fully understand what you mean by your comment.

Comment: For the same reason that a ball that is high in the air falls down because of its potential energy.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you want , I think can be found using energy considerations. Thomsons theorem states that given a certain total charge on a number of surfaces, the configuration of the system such that the field energy is minimised requires each of the surfaces to be an equipotential. For more rigorous mathematical proofs you can google for many papers on this theorem and its extensions. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Others have given good answers in terms of math and electromagnetics. I think it may help to have a conceptual answer too.

Let's use an analogy between electric charge and the simple mechanics of water.

In a water system, potential energy is due to gravity. Water raised up high in a water tower or a lake on a hill has higher potential energy than water at ground level. In a water system, voltage is analogous to the height difference in the two bodies of water, and charge is analogous to the amount of water.

Let's say you connected a water tower to a tank at ground level with a pipe. When you open the valve on the pipe, which way will the water flow? Down of course.

But note I didn't have to tell you which tank was larger. Whether the tank in the tower has more water or less than the tank at ground level, the water always flows down. That's because without outside influence, the water will always flow from the higher potential to the lower.

The same is true in an electrical system. The flow of charge is always from higher to lower potential. The amount of charge on either end will affect the rate of flow and other interesting things, but not the direction of flow.

Water flows downhill. Charge also flows "downhill" in terms of potential.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does electric charge flow direction depend on the potential difference [...]

Because a system will always want to minimize it's energy. Just like a book falls to lower height (lower gravitational potential energy), a charge will move towards a point which it is repelled the least from (lowest electrical potential energy).

> [...] and not the charge difference between two points?

**Untrue**. Their *sign* difference *does matter*! Different signs attract, equal signs repel.

Now, their difference in *magnitude* seems not to matter - at first sight.
But imagine having 10 negative charges at one point and just 2 negative charges at another point. Then a new added negative charge will be repelled **more** from the first point than from the latter and will of course rather move towards the latter - which is exactly what *potential energy* means.

So charge magnitude *does* matter on direction, and is the reason for potential energy.